# Need help solving this bad edgeflow

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges, retopology

I'm fairly new to this and while following a YouTube tutorial I've came across this problem of bad edgeflow as you can see here [image]
[image]

I don't know how to work around it. I tried cutting with knife tool but it made it worse. I want these blue edges to completely follow through to the end. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

always use Quads to have a better control of the topology avoid N-gon and vertices where more than 4 edges converge

[image: Errors]

[image: s]

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that pentagon there. Does that break edge loop? And in the second image what's the "4 lines" you're referring to?